# Bluetooth headphones crashes laptop

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headphones, bluez

When I'm working I listen to music over my Bluetooth headphones (Sennheiser HD 4.40) through Spotify. After some random minutes I hear a bit of a delay in the music, my Bluetooth mouse is lagging and after some more seconds everything freezes. I'm not able to kill a process and get the laptop to work again. I need to turn it off, the hard way by pressing the power button for 5 seconds. After boot up everything is working again.
My `bluez` is up to date, version: `bluez is already the newest version (5.50-0ubuntu4).`
I tried for several hours not to use the headphones and everything is fine. So that is why I think the headphones are causing the problem.
If there is anything I can add to provide more information, let me know I will update my question.
Thanks!

--- Additional Information ---

@Pouyan said that the information of journalctl could be helpful, so I ran the command `journalctl --since="2020-01-09 10:00:00" -p err`

```
Jan 09 10:35:22 fritzschoff bluetoothd[1123]: Unable to get io data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
-- Reboot --
```

I use the mic from my laptop for zoom and slack. Not sure if this is important to know.

Another good entry:

```
Jan 09 15:42:02 fritzschoff acpid[1138]: input device has been disconnected, fd 23
Jan 09 15:42:02 fritzschoff /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1838]: (II) config/udev: removing device 00:16:94:35:44:E5
Jan 09 15:42:02 fritzschoff /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1838]: (**) Option "fd" "77"
Jan 09 15:42:02 fritzschoff /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1838]: (II) event22 - 00:16:94:35:44:E5: device removed
Jan 09 15:42:02 fritzschoff /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1838]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Jan 09 15:42:02 fritzschoff /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1838]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:86
Jan 09 15:42:02 fritzschoff bluetoothd[1149]: Unable to get io data for Headset Voice gateway: getpeername: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)
Jan 09 15:42:02 fritzschoff gsd-media-keys[2302]: Unable to get default sink
Jan 09 15:42:02 fritzschoff dbus-daemon[1152]: [system] Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.243" (uid=1000 pid=2129 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize
```

Comment: Can you copy the information from `journalctl` from the last boot till you shutdown your computer. Normally the situation will be logged there. And can help to debug the problem.

Comment: any idea how to fix the problem here?