# Bluetooth headphone crashes(freezes) my laptop screen

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, headphones, bluez, bluetooth-speaker

When i listen to songs or videos via my bluetooth headphones, it works fine for sometimes but after a while sound starts lagging and then my screen freezes and then needed to hard reboot. This happens only when i use  wireless bluetooth devices.My question exactly matches this:- [Bluetooth headphones crashes laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1201697/bluetooth-headphones-crashes-laptop)

Please help me for this.

Output of `journalctl` :-

```
brijeshvp@brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30:~$ journalctl
-- Logs begin at Thu 2020-07-30 03:11:47 IST, end at Sun 2020-08-02 08:56:02 IST
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: microcode: microcode updated ear
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: Linux version 5.3.0-40-generic (
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/v
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: KERNEL supported cpus:
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel:   Intel GenuineIntel
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel:   AMD AuthenticAMD
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel:   Hygon HygonGenuine
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel:   Centaur CentaurHauls
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel:   zhaoxin   Shanghai  
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: x86/fpu: x87 FPU will use FXSAVE
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000000
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009e8
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000e00
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000001000
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000200000
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000201000
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000785450
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000078b450
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000078c450
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000078c850
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000796f20
lines 1-23...skipping...
-- Logs begin at Thu 2020-07-30 03:11:47 IST, end at Sun 2020-08-02 08:56:02 IST. --
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x838, date = 2019-04-22
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: Linux version 5.3.0-40-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-024) (gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)) #32~18.04.1-
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-40-generic root=UUID=593503d4-edad-484c-b186-ff73fe57893b ro initrd=/casper
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: KERNEL supported cpus:
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel:   Intel GenuineIntel
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel:   AMD AuthenticAMD
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel:   Hygon HygonGenuine
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel:   Centaur CentaurHauls
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel:   zhaoxin   Shanghai  
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: x86/fpu: x87 FPU will use FXSAVE
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009e7ff] usable
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009e800-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000e0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x000000001fffffff] usable
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000020000000-0x00000000200fffff] reserved
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000020100000-0x0000000078544fff] usable
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000078545000-0x0000000078b44fff] reserved
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000078b45000-0x0000000078c44fff] ACPI NVS
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000078c45000-0x0000000078c84fff] ACPI data
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000078c85000-0x00000000796f1fff] usable
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000796f2000-0x0000000079ff1fff] ACPI NVS
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000079ff2000-0x0000000079ffffff] usable
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007a000000-0x000000007a7fffff] reserved
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007ae00000-0x000000007fffffff] reserved
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000e0000000-0x00000000e3ffffff] reserved
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec00000-0x00000000fec00fff] reserved
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed01000-0x00000000fed01fff] reserved
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed03000-0x00000000fed03fff] reserved
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed08000-0x00000000fed08fff] reserved
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed0c000-0x00000000fed0ffff] reserved
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed1c000-0x00000000fed1cfff] reserved
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fee00000-0x00000000fee00fff] reserved
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fef00000-0x00000000feffffff] reserved
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ffc00000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000017fffffff] usable
Jul 30 03:11:47 brijeshvp-Lenovo-G50-30 kernel: NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
```

Comment: anyone please help me. i am facing this problem a lot & getting interrupted from my work due to system crash